# print contents of file until found the word hi

Tags: php, filesystems

I want the program to print the document contents line by line while not reaching neither the end of file or found the word `hi`

The problem is when it found the word `hi`, it prints nothing although it is at position 22. Why not print the previous words  how to solve this issue.

My file contain "Php is a special case `hi`. You will use less memory using the iterative solution. Moreover, function calls in PHP are costly, so it's better to avoid function calls when you can." string.
Here is my code

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents('m.txt');
$search_keyword =  'hi';

// check if word is there
$file=fopen("m.txt","r+");

while(!feof($file)&&strpos($contents, $search_keyword) == FALSE)
{

    echo fgets($file)."<br>";

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

change this condition

```
while(!feof($file)&&strpos($contents, $search_keyword) == FALSE)
```

to

```
while(!feof($file)) {
    if(strpos($contents, $search_keyword) === FALSE) {
         echo fgets($file)."<br>";
    } else
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i want print the contents of the file befor hi word only that code 
prevent other contents of document from printing did u get it??

Comment: same pro
look what i want is print the file line by line until the word 'hi' is found

Comment: not it stops when it say the word hi without printing any statement 
have u try it??

Answer (score 0):

You mean print the file line by line until the word 'hi' is found?

```
<?php
$search_keyword = 'hi';
$handle = @fopen("m.txt", "r");
if ( $handle )
{
    // Read file one line at a time
    while ( ($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false )
    {
        echo $buffer . '<br />';

        if ( preg_match('/'.$search_keyword.'/i', $subject) )
            break;
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

You can replace the `preg_match` to `strpos` if you like.

Comment: here is the output the result of text after hi still shown

Php is a special case hi. You will use less memory using the iterative solution. Moreover, function calls in PHP are costly, so it's better to avoid function calls when you can.

Notice: Undefined variable: subject in G:\xampp\htdocs\zdss\hiline.php on line 11